# extended generic does not overlap with a similar structural-typing type assignment

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I don't understand the [following typing error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgd0QS2BAPAFQDRQCqAfFALxQAKaAxgNa4ECiAHjQDYCuAJtnRCAD2AMyj4o-IaJKkAZEQDcAKCWhIUAGIQI3AEYBDeuQDeSqFDUQAXFADkSRIMS2oAHzsBnTjRoQPH22UAXxUaQQA7D2AofQ1OcJpyKCwAZU5dAFsMACU-TnZgHHBoCBZMcO4PKGNhbT1DOhstHQN6IOIACgBKclJjc3MzAbDI6Mwomxgs4FT06dyvAqLIPFtalobbOWr1+vobcPz2IKSautbGqEP2Y+DlJVj4miwzjf3mvboCQWAACyQbFF0OEAObtboKIA) typescript raises:

```js
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U;

type Feedback ={
  type: 'error' | 'success';
}

const aFunc = <SubmitResultType extends {feedback: Feedback}>() => {    
    const test: Omit<SubmitResultType,'feedback'> & {feedback: null} = {feedback: null};
};

aFunc<{feedback:Feedback, other: string}>();
```

```
    Type '{ feedback: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Omit<SubmitResultType, "feedback"> & { feedback: null; }'.
      Type '{ feedback: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Omit<SubmitResultType, "feedback">'.
    'test' is declared but its value is never read.
```

In my head, thanks to the structural typing, `test` variable, its typing and its assignment should be working fine

Comment: BTW `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>>` is just `Omit<T, keyof U>` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys

Comment: no, I don't want `Partial`. Actually, what I want is fully understanding the cause of `b`'s typing to be incompatible with `param`, if `b`'s assignment is logically a verified narrowed case. There's something I don't consider/ I'm ignoring

Comment: You're hitting multiple problems here: narrowing a property doesn't narrow the parent (see [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384)) and even if it did, the compiler wouldn't necessarily follow the higher-order logic for generics in `Exclude` (see [ms/TS#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884), note that `Omit` uses `Exclude` and you've essentially rewritten `Omit`). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: We're almost there: I could simplify the example with `Omit`  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYlKATARgQwMYGsYF4YDewMJM40AXDAORQBOdA9ndTAD40DOArhhlJ07UA3MAC+wYFAAeEZiDKRYAOUYA7ZdwA2WtCi1QACkwgAeACoAaGAGkAfHkIBtQzACWamFihhGAMxhzAF0qVxkQKDUkTlsYAH4YVQ1tXX0oCxcghypzTLFRclgAeQA3egB3OjcIi2sAVQd8IoBbatqvH38YBpgAMm7RYAx1TgU0OG41DEcLGHDI6MIYP0RUTCwqBGR0bHYYNRSYMTsACgg0OjRmnIBKPAciEmIYYbVRmDRHc8vm0RI3PxnC5XAB0K226zwuHwBx0d0epFe7xQVFKFSqNSshHBa2wVFhWmOX2Bv2eEnEoiAA

Comment: I'm confused; yes, you could simplify to `Omit` as multiple previous comments have mentioned, but does that change anything with regard to the situation? Could you please respond to the substance of my comment so I can know how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Simply commenting I can improve the question with the `Omit` so that you can quote the question - if needed - with a better source. I'll proceed, and about your question: yes, your comment does answer the question

Comment: Is there a reason you rolled back to the problematic version which would need `Partial` to make sense? Could you please [edit] to improve the question however you'd like that demonstrates the actual issue (and feel free to use `Omit`) and then I'll answer it?